Problem in scarthgap Yocto project and devtool
In our yocto project we cannot use the devtool to get the kernel into workspace/source after moving from mickledore to scarthgap.
We get an error on "devtool modify linux-stable":

ERROR: Applying patch 'linux-6.1.89.patch' on target directory
'/Yocto/TestScarthgap/build/tmp/work/rock_4-poky-linux/linux-stable/6.1.89/devtooltmp-62stdz1s/workdir/linux-6.1'CmdError('sh
-c 'PATCHFILE="linux-6.1.89.patch" git -c user.name="OpenEmbedded" -c user.email="oe.patch@oe" commit -F /tmp/tmpzs0ji_ce --no-verify'', 0,
'stdout:stderr: Aborting commit due to empty commit message.')ERROR:
Logfile of failure stored in:
/Yocto/TestScarthgap/build/tmp/work/rock_4-poky-linux/linux-stable/6.1.89/devtooltmp-62stdz1s/temp/log.do_patch.3398020

We are using the meta-linux-mainline layer.
There are no problems to put on the patch by hand.
We have tried it with another Kernel version and it does not work and reports the same error.
We had no problems when we use the Yocto mickledore release.
As mentioned, we were working OK with mickledore and have moved to scarthgap.
We have no problems with building our images, and have no problems with a "devtool modify u-boot" which works correctly.
We only have a problem with the "devtool modify linux-stable"

In my case, the issue was that the .patch files I used did not have a Git commit header such as:
From abcdef1234567890 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Your Name <your.email@example.com>
Date: Mon, 1 Jan 2024 12:00:00 +0000
Subject: [PATCH] <Commit Message>

As created by e. g. git format-patch -1 HEAD

The problem is that the kernel patch, (in this case linux-6.1.89.patch),  that comes off of the web does not have the header!
